# main title in grid.arrange or arrangeGrob has a grey background

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridextra

I am switching from `ggplot2 1.0.1` and `gridExtra 0.9.1` to the newest versions of these packages and struggle with some minor issues at the moment.

One problem is the title in a combined plot.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
df <- data.frame(x=runif(100), y=runif(100))
p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) + geom_point()
p2 <- ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) + geom_point()
a <- arrangeGrob(p1,p1,p2, layout_matrix=rbind(c(1,2),c(1,3)), top='my title')
plot(a)
ggsave('a.pdf', a)
```

in the older version, the parameter was called `main` and I had to use `print` to plot my graphics `a`. Now, when I save the graph, everything is fine. But the `plot(a)` graph has the light grey grid background behind the `my title`. In the saved pdf file, the background is white again.

I also tried to use `grid.arrange` but I don't want to print the plot directly when executing. Thats why I use the two step approach by saving the graph in a variable and then `plot` it.

So, how do I get a white background when `plot(a)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `grid.draw`. The `plot` method is for testing only.

```
library(grid)
grid.newpage() 
grid.draw(a)
```

[image: resulting plot]

Comment: hach, thats not very intuitive... But ok, it works like this. The `grid.newpage` is recommended? Or when do I need it?! I loved the "old" possibility by using `print`, unfortunately, this is no longer possible.

Comment: I agree that `plot` is more intuitive. I was educated regarding using `grid.draw` by baptiste when mistakenly recommending `plot` as a substitute for `print` after the update. You need `grid.newpage` if you want a new page. Otherwise this might print on top of an existent grid plot.

Comment: btw I don't take responsibility for those choices: `grid.draw` is the standard grid convention, while plot and print were once inherited from lattice/ggplot2, but that gtable developers decided to change.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning grid.newpage(). It was needed to **clear out old titles** in my case. The titles were overlapping.